# Whats the meaning of this notation?

Tags: notation

Whats the meaning of this symbol:

[image: Symbol]

The vertical line and the small beta coefficients to its right? The context: the derivative is part of the least squares method in simple regression analysis. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the partial derivative of $S$ with respect to $\beta_0$, evaluated at $\beta_0 = \hat{\beta}_0$, $\beta_1 = \hat{\beta}_1$.